# Prove the existence of a point not accounted for by mapping from N to R and deduce uncountability of R from this

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let a:  $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be given. For $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < b$
show that there is a point $c$ in the closed interval $I = [a, b]$ such that
$c \notin \{a(n) | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Conclude from this that $I$, and hence $\mathbb{R}$ also, are
uncountable. (Hint: By induction define a sequence $I = I_0 \supset I_1 \supset\cdots$ of
closed intervals such that $a(n) \notin I_{n+1}$ and use the fact that $\displaystyle\bigcap_n I_n\neq\emptyset$)

I'm currently working over this proof from the book Mathematical Logic by Ebbinghaus, Flumm, and Thomas. I'm a complete beginner in mathematical logic so please bear with me.

How does one go about proving this? So far I've tried Cantor's diagonalisation argument to no avail, for I can't seem to be able to figure out the mapping (most probably because of my limited understanding of it). Is it a correct way to prove the above or should I try something else? Is there a simpler or more intuitive way to approach this? (Seeing as this proof-excercise is on the very first chapter of the book while the diagonal argument is first mentioned in a much later one).

Thank you for your time.

UPDATE: If anyone stumbles upon this question/has the same question, I found the following topics illuminating:

- Cantor's Proofs of Uncountability of R (especially his first proof which seems to be directly linked to the one I posted here)
- Nested Intervals Theorem/Cantor's Intersection Theorem and proofs of uncountability of R using them

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that, for a series of closed intervals, where each contains the last, their intersection cannot be empty? This is a very useful fact here. Also, note that, to choose an I_n, just take some subset of I_(n-1) not containing f(n).

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I had incorrectly assumed that the hint was pertaining to the second part of the proof. Is f(n) the mapping a? Could you elaborate on the choosing of the sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I will write $a_n$ in place of $a(n)$.

So, following the hint here is what we do. Start out by defining $I_0=[a,b]$. Now according to the hint we don't want $a_0$ to lie in $I_1$, so we need to pick a closed interval contained in $[a,b]$ which does not contain $a_0$. If $a_0$ is not in this interval, then that's easy, we can just take $I_1=[a,b]$ again. If however $a_0$ is in the interval, then we could try

$$I_1=\left[\frac{a_0+b}{2},b\right]$$

This works according to the hint, because: since $a_0\in[a,b]$, $a_0<b$, and so $\frac{a_0+b}{2}<\frac{b+b}{2}=b$, or in other words this closed interval actually makes sense to define. Moreover, $a_0=\frac{a_0+a_0}{2}<\frac{a_0+b}{2}$, so $a_0\notin I_1$. Finally, both $a_0\geq a$ and $b>a$, so their average $\frac{a_0+b}{2}>a$, meaning that $I_1\subset I_0$.

Well, it almost works. I forgot to account for the case where $a_0=b$. If that happens to be the case, we can always just use the other endpoint though, defining instead:

$$I_1=\left[a,\frac{a_0+a}{2}\right]$$

and this works just as well, so long as $a<a_0$.

We can use this exact same idea to inductively define the sequence of nested intervals. So, let $I_0=[a,b]$.

Suppose $I_n=[c,d]$, $c<d$ is defined already. If $a_n\notin I_n$, then let $I_{n+1}=I_n$. Otherwise, $c\leq a_n\leq d$.

If $a_n=d$, then define

$$I_n=\left[c,\frac{a_n+c}{2}\right]$$

and otherwise (so $a_n<d$) let

$$I_n=\left[\frac{a_n+d}{2},d\right].$$

Now I will leave it to you to verify a couple of things:

- $a_n\notin I_{n+1}$
- $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$
- the endpoints of $I_{n+1}$ are not the same, provided the endpoints of $I_n$ are not (we did use the fact that $c<d$, otherwise it would be possible for $I_n=[a_n,a_n]$, and then we would be really stuck)

By induction this gives us a sequence of closed, nested intervals $I_0\subset I_1\subset I_2\subset\cdots$, such that $a_n\notin I_{n+1}$.

Now we consider the intersection $X=\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} I_n$. By [Cantor's Intersection Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem) (which is what I presume the book is referring to), this intersection is nonempty. However, $a_n\notin X$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Why? because if it were in the intersection, then it would have to lie in every single interval. However $a_n\notin I_{n+1}$.

So, we have a nonempty set containing no elements of $\{a_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Therefore  the mapping was not surjective, which was what we wanted to show.

Comment: Can you explain the process behind choosing the half-way point between a_0 and b as a? Can't one simply choose a_0+1 thus guaranteeing that a_0 is not in I_1?

Comment: But what if the interval's width is less than 1? You need to choose something like the average to guarantee each successive interval is actually a well defined internal, because the intervals could potentially get arbitrarily small. Any point between $a_0$ and $b$ will do, the average is just the simplest one to describe.

Comment: So now that I've proved that I is uncountable, does proving that there is an injective or surjective mapping from I to R or R to I prove that R is too uncountable? How do I go about defining that mapping? I seem to have problem visualising and defining such mappings. Is there something (a theorem,axiom etc) that defines mappings between uncountable sets?

Comment: All subsets of a countable set are either finite or countably infinite. If $\mathbb{R}$ were countable, then the interval $I$ would be too, however we just showed that $I$ is uncountable. There are mappings between intervals and $\mathbb{R}$ but we don't need to show that $\mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinality as $I$, just that it is uncountable.